# Proof by induction (using base case and inductive step)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

I'm struggling to write a proof for the following using proof by induction:

Let Y be a set of size $i$, where $i ∈ ℕ$. Prove:
    $$|\{X ⊆ Y: |X| = 2\}| = {i(i-1)\over 2}$$

How would I prove this using a base case and inductive step.

Comment: I've removed the "proof-theory" tag - it refers to [a specific subfield of mathematical logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/), not general questions about proofs.

Comment: For clarification; do you specifically want an inductive proof or do you want any proof?  I think a direct proof is easier and more convincing.

Comment: @fleablood it needs to be inductive

Answer (score 1):

Induction step:

So you have now $i+1$ elements. Without Loss of Generality we may assume that $Y=\{1,2,3,…,i,i+1\}$ You can make ${i(i-1)\over 2}$ sets with 2 elements in a set with $i$ elements by I.H. Now how many two element sets we have with element $i+1$ in it?

Since we can pair $i+1$ with each element, we have $i$ such sets, so now you have $${i(i-1)\over 2}+i$$ such sets. OK?

Comment: You should include the phrase "Without Loss of Generality we may assume that $Y=\{1,2,3,\dots,i,i+1\}$"  Otherwise, there is no reason to assume that the set actually has "element $i+1$" in it since the statement is about *all* possible sets with $i$ elements.

Comment: @aqua thanks for your reply, please could you explain it in more detail as I am slightly confused

Comment: Just make the set $Y_i = \{a_j, j=1\text{ to }i\}$.